# Use virt-manager on windows with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, qemu, virt-manager

I current am trying to connect to a hyper visor server with `virt-manager` on a windows computer. The host is currently setup to run only as a TTY base server. And from my research, I've only read to use `PuTTY` and `Xming` and have `virt-manager` to run over SSH. Witch has horrible latency.

My question is how can i install `cygwin` and use `virt-manager` with little hassle.

As of so far, I had installed cygwin and a ton of X.org components, but I get a "failed to connect to display" I had tried one link and got the `virt-manager` to launch, but as soon as i try to connect to the system with QEMU+SSH, it crashes with no error to print.

Comment: Not sure your issue, would need more details probably. But see my answer here >> https://serverfault.com/questions/340949/is-there-a-way-to-run-virt-manager-on-windows. I use virt-manager on Win10 LTSB x64 to manage a Fedora 27 KVM Host w/o issues.

Answer (score 2):

When setting up Cygwin don't just install "everything" you can install via "groups" which will install required dependencies.

You need to install the following packages:

```
virt-manager, xinit and openssh
```

Configure SSH Passwordless Login via RSA in the Cygwin Terminal and then test launching Virt-Manager. Then you can look into creating a shortcut as I did.

I did create a youtube video as well. Please see this question for more details.

https://serverfault.com/questions/340949/is-there-a-way-to-run-virt-manager-on-windows